# Need recommendation on appropriate primary key structure

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

I have a lot of time series data that I would like to store in a Cassandra database.  Since I can only do `WHERE` clauses on fields in the primary key, I need some recommendations on how to lay this out based on the way that I will need to query it.

My data is in this format:

```
SYSTEM_SERIAL_NUMBER,DEVICE_ID,TIMESTAMP,...OTHER COLUMNS
```

Each serial number has multiple devices, and I will have thousands of timestamps for every device, so my primary key to uniquely identify each set of data has to include all three.

There are basically two types of queries I will do on this data.

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE system_serial_number = 'X' and device_id = 'x' and timestamp` (is in a range)

or

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE system_serial_number = 'X' and timestamp` (is in a range)

The second one is the more likely query, because I am typically going to input a time range in the application and I want to see data from every single device for a given serial number.  But I can't leave the device name out of the key because you need serial/device/timestamp to be able to uniquely identify an entire row.

I've tried to create my tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
system_serial_number text,
device_id int,
time_stamp timestamp,
...,
PRIMARY KEY ((system_serial_number,device_id),time_stamp)
);
```

And also as:

```
CREATE TABLE devices (
system_serial_number text,
device_id int,
time_stamp timestamp,
...,
PRIMARY KEY (system_serial_number,device_id,time_stamp)
);
```

The first one I think would keep me from hitting column limitations, but it always requires me to enter a Device ID along with the Serial every time I query.  The second one is less column efficient (based on my understanding), and it allows me to search by serial only.  Neither one of them lets me search by just serial/timestamp, which is actually the most common search that I am going to do, but isn't unique enough to be a primary key.

The only way I've even been able to get a query to work is by using the first one with the compound key and then adding a secondary index for just serial number, which then allows me to search by serial/timestamp, but I have to use the inefficient `ALLOW FILTERING`.

Any suggestions on the best way to get what I need?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is:

```
PRIMARY KEY (system_serial_number, time_stamp, device_id)
```

- `system_serial_number` will be the *partition key* that identifies which replicas (nodes) will contain the data.  All data for a single serial number will need to fit in the same partition.  For efficient access, all queries will be required to specify a serial number.  If partition size is a concern, there may be ways to further subdivide if the use case allows.
- `time_stamp` will be the *clustering key* used to sort the rows within the partition.  That is, all logical rows for the same serial number will be ordered by the timestamp, irrespective of the device.  The first PK column that is *not a part of the partition key* determines the sort order.
- `device_id` is an additional PK column to distinguish your logical rows, but does not help you sort or do other range scans.

Since you mentioned that each device would generate thousands of timestamps, and each serial number will have many devices, you may also need to be concerned about the size of your partitions if you take the above approach.  A common approach is to break the data for a single serial number across multiple partitions, but that can make querying your data either more efficient or more troublesome, depending on how you decide to subdivide the data.

You will have to use some imagination and knowledge of your specific use cases to decide on the proper partitioning layout.  Off the top of my head, I can think of some ideas:

- `PRIMARY KEY ((system_serial_number, device_hash_modulus), time_stamp, device_id)`

  - Idea: hash your device IDs and apply a modulus to split the data across a fixed number of "buckets"
  - Advantage: with an even hash distribution, spreads data evenly across a known number of nodes
  - Disadvantage: querying across "all devices" for a given serial number requires making *N* queries, one for each "bucket" based on the number chosen for the modulo operation
  - Disadvantage: may need to adjust bucketing scheme (and migrate data) if initial choice is too small for eventual data size
- `PRIMARY KEY ((system_serial_number, coarse_time_stamp), time_stamp, device_id)`

  - Idea: split the data over time into different partitions, size determined by how *coarse* you make the partitioning timestamp (year? year+month?, year+day?, etc.).  The decision should be made based on how many unique records are expected within a given time period.
  - Advantage: assuming the cluster is configured with a *random partitioner*, the data will be evenly distributed around the cluster as time moves forward.
  - Disadvantage: querying for records across a *range of time* may involve making separate queries to different partitions, making the program logic more complex.  If the partition timestamp isn't coarse enough, or the timestamp range to be searched is too wide, performance will be impacted.

There may be other options available to you, but it will all depend on how well you understand your current use cases (and how well you can predict the future behavior of your data set).